# Null returned for getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email")

Tags: android, email, android-intent, nullpointerexception

My aim is to launch Email client on Android device using:

```
Intent regularIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");

if (regularIntent == null) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This Email client not configured!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {

    regularIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivityForResult(regularIntent,0);
}
```

I always get regularIntent as Null. What is a workaround for this issue?

Comment: what is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to open the Email client via that regularIntent so user can import files. It works great for Gmail:
Intent importIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
if (importIntent == null) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gmail client not configured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
     importIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);startActivityForResult(importIntent,0);}

Comment: The package name changed for 4.1 and above for Email client app on Android devices. The correct package name is "com.google.android.email" instead of "com.android.email". That replacement solved my problem.